# TIP 120 vs TIP141

Tags: transistors

I was wondering what are the major differences between TIP120 and TIP141?

Currently it seems they are both NPN, but TIP141 can handle a larger current.

Would these two be interchangeable?

I am looking at tutorials involving arduino with TIP120 to drive a string of LEDs.

However I am using high powered LEDs and the TIP120 can't handle the load, so is it possible to interchange it to TIP141?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TIP120 is an NPN Darlington  in a TO-220 package and is rated at 60V/5A (subject to heatsink)

Gain is 1000 min @3A

The TIP141 is an NPN Darlington in a TO-247 package and is rated at 80V/10A "

Gain is 1000 min @5A

The forward drop won't be much different on the two, they're both NPN Darlingtons, so simply replacing one with the other won't give you much more current capability if the heatsink is not increased. So, in answer to your question, it's possible, but it doesn't buy you much (well, if you had no heatsink at all, the TO-247 is relatively large compared to a TO-220 so it would have a higher capability by 50-100% on that account, but you'd buy just as much by attaching a few square inches of aluminum to the tab).

It would be better to use a low Rds(on) MOSFET to switch the LEDs, with a suitable MOSFET you would not require a heatsink at all, even at 10A.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to interchange them. As both transistors specify the same gain (at least 1000), you might need to decrease the base resistor to obtain the higher collector current. If you need more than 5 amps, you are most likely using PWM or plain on/off, so you need to make sure the base current is high enough that the transistor saturates, because otherwise the voltage drop across the transistor would generate too much heat.

Nevertheless, Speluro is right that with such high currents, a low Rds(on) MOSFET is likely a superior option. If it is a logic-level FET, at can directly be driven from the arduino.